# When ios7 releases, will apps with iOS 6 and older style UI be rejected?

Tags: ios, appstore-approval, ios7

I have developed an app for a customer which is live on app store. The app should support iOS v4.3 and later.
When i build the app in xcode 4.5 with ios sdk 6, and install it on a device running iOS 7 beta 3, the app works without any issues.
But the appearence of the app is pre-ios7 with opaque status bar. 
My question is how strict is the ios 7 UI guideline.. Will my app in the existing state be rejected from app store after ios7 release??

Regards

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not sure we are even allowed to talk about this since iOS 7 is still under NDA. Please ask the same question under the Apple Developer forums.

Comment: @user559668: did you find more info about it? thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe, maybe not. No one knows except of the people at Apple and they won't tell you. So the answer is a definite: Maybe.

Comment: My first thought was, "They probably won't reject it". My second thought was, "It really wouldn't surprise me if they rejected it."

Comment: None of the guidelines even in iOS6 have been absolute rules. Look at Clear. Nothing like iOS6 style.

Comment: I'd guess they won't reject apps with the old style at the beginning, but I would expect them to do so at some time later. Remember the introduction of the iPhone 5 and the requirement to support it's screen size. iPhone 5 was released 09/2012, requirement to support it is enforced since 05/2013. So I'd guess you have at least 3-6 months time before Apple enforces iOS 7 UI support. Nevertheless, you should start updating the design of your apps to the iOS 7 style ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

Can't say for sure. But my thoughts are they are not going to reject your app for iOS 7 UI Guidelines. That will be strongly suggested guidelines but not must have.